# How to get the value of intensity map,color map,orientation map of an image in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, toolbox

I am trying to get the unique values of any object in imae processing , such as its color map value, intensity and orientation in matlab, i got the saliency map for the objects but i couldn't extract the above Values from the saliency map ,  can you give any tips on how to find it ?

Comment: Are you using http://www.saliencytoolbox.net/ or some other set of code? Hint: you don't get those values from the saliency map, you get them in the process of computing the saliency map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate mean intensity for the whole image . we can convert the input rgb img to grayscale,  then third line will give the intensity value input_rgbimg=imread('imagefilename.jpg');Inimg=rgb2gray(input_rgbimg);
intensity_img=mean2(Inimg); it will be in floating point format..